# changing the .jsp extension to .xyz in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello by changing the extension of jsp to ex : xyz the eclipse editor can't recognition the file is jsp how I can add my custom extension to eclipse ide for behavior like jsp?
I added this line to my web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.xyz</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would add `*.xyz` to the JSP entry on the [Content Types](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-content-type.htm?cp=0_4_1_15) preference page. It's under "Text".

[image: content type preference page]